# Search multiple columns and return top cell value

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I have an `INDEX` formula that will take a value from the first cell in a row, search multiple columns of another sheet for a match and return the corresponding header row value when the match is found.

The problem is that I have to manually copy this formula down in order for it to apply to every row.  But more to the point, if I edit the formula or create new rows, I need to make sure I apply that edit to every row.  I would much rather have a single formula at the top of the column that applies to all cells below.

```
=INDEX(subTaskCategories!$C$1:$J$1,MAX(IF(subTaskCategories!$C$2:$J=A2,COLUMN(subTaskCategories!$C$2:$J)-COLUMN(A2)-1)))
```

What is an alternative to `INDEX` that will search multiple columns and return the header when a match is found that can also be wrapped in an `ARRAYFORMULA`?

[My sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Za3a9d3hKJCMAxy72sIRH9L61wLwvBw02Fwj_9E_z-4/edit#gid=1609799406&range=C2) in subTaskData!C2

Comment: In principle you can  use Hlookup or Vlookup as an alternative to Index, but the problem is more that Max doesn't work with array formulas either, and that you're already working with a 2d array.

Comment: @player0 I edited the question to include a link to my sheet

Comment: @TomSharpe I don’t think I necessarily need `MAX`. Seems like `ARRAYFORMULA` will automatically fill to the bottom row anyway. As I understand it

Comment: subTaskData!C2 (edited in question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste in **B2** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(C2:C, "^~ (.*) ~$"), 
 TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(INDIRECT("taskCategories!C2:"&ADDRESS(ROWS(taskCategories!A1:A), 
 COLUMNS(taskCategories!A1:AA1), 4))<>"", "♥"&INDIRECT("taskCategories!C2:"&
 ADDRESS(ROWS(taskCategories!A1:A), COLUMNS(taskCategories!A1:AA1), 4))&"♦"&
 INDIRECT("taskCategories!C1:"&ADDRESS(1, COLUMNS(taskCategories!A1:AA1), 4)), ))
 , , 999^99)), , 999^99), "♥")), "♦")), 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

---

paste in **C2** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(INDIRECT("subtaskCategories!C2:"&ADDRESS(ROWS(subTaskCategories!A1:A), 
 COLUMNS(subTaskCategories!A1:AA1), 4))<>"", "♥"&INDIRECT("subtaskCategories!C2:"&
 ADDRESS(ROWS(subTaskCategories!A1:A), COLUMNS(subTaskCategories!A1:AA1), 4))&"♦"&
 INDIRECT("subtaskCategories!C1:"&ADDRESS(1, COLUMNS(subTaskCategories!A1:AA1), 4)), ))
 , , 999^99)), , 999^99), "♥")), "♦")), 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Wow!  There's a lot going on in those formulas!  Thanks again!